# How to find week first and last date for selected date in php?

Tags: php

I intend on retrieving the date field of weeks of all the values. But am having trouble getting accurate answers. I need to get the separated week all date for the selected date and also find week first and last date of week.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please show us come code otherwise this just looks like a specification and we dont code from specifications

Comment: To ask an On Topic question, please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Seriously, there are a ton of similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+first+last+day+of+week. It's impossible to know where to even start answering this. Try something, and ask us about concrete problems with your concrete approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Try this

- It will be useful for you.

  ```
    $date = isset($_GET['date']) ? $_GET['date'] : date('d-m-Y');
       $start_date =  date("d-m-Y",strtotime('monday this week',strtotime($date)));
  ```

  `$end_date =  date("d-m-Y", strtotime('saturday this week',strtotime($date)));`

  - use $start_date to find weeks first date
  - use $end_date to find weeks last date